# Need Bootable CD To Kickstart Hard Drive Boot

Tags: boot, bios

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from DVD to an internal hard drive but the BIOS doesn't recognize the hard drive during boot.  If I boot from DVD the hard drive is attached to the file system and polulated as expected.  The hard drive will boot fine in another machine so it seems that this is a BIOS problem with the original machine.  The problem is not limited to this new Ubuntu drive; a known good Windows drive is also not recognized by the BIOS and won't boot.

A solution I've considered is a generic Linux boot from CD/USB which in turn kicks off the Ubuntu boot from the installed hard drive.  Can anyone recommend such a "boot wrapper" program? (or another solution)

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry for putting this as answer but i couldn't comment - low rep.
you mean it does not even load grub? i installed ubuntu before some days and i had similar problems. Grub wasn't installed.
So i had to boot from grub-rescue.
Since you can boot from DVD you can try these from a terminal
`sudo update-grub`
then do
`sudo grub-install /dev/sd*`
where * is the drive you want grub to be installed

Comment: I don't believe the problem is the hard drive itself; the hard drive boots fine on another machine.  I believe the problem is the BIOS in that it doesn't recognize the hard drive.  What I want to try is to boot from DVD which will in turn kicks off a boot from the hard drive without involving the BIOS.

Comment: just in case, let me ask you,
have you changed the boot order from your bios after the installation?
In case you didn't, there is an option when you open bios settings where you can choose boot device order, that's where you should pick hdd as the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command

```
sudo gparted
```

If gparted (disk manager) is not installed, an error message will be displayed, saying that you do not have it yet. If this is the case, install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

After the installation ends, make sure your DVD is **inserted but not mounted**, run `sudo gparted` again and it will open.

Click the tab "GParted" > "Devices" and select your DVD. Its informations will be showed.

Right-click your DVD tab (probably /dev/sdb/c/d or other letter) and click "Manage Flags". Select "Boot" and confirm.

Now you have to confirm your actions. Click the green "V" (Apply Actions) button below the tab "Device". Wait for the process to end, close GParted and now your DVD should be recognized.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem isn't with the DVD player, the BIOS doesn't seem to recognize the hard drive.  I can successfully boot from the DVD and mount the hard drive so I know the hard drive itself is good.  In addition the hard drive boots in another machine just fine.  What I want to do is either:
* get the hard drive to be recognized by the BIOS (it won't recognize a Windows drive either so this isn't limited to Ubuntu)
-OR-
* have a boot DVD which will mount the hard drive and then boot from the hard drive